# Laravel - Login redirect problem for subdomain

Tags: laravel, subdomain

i have a site

```
http://mysite.test/login
```

now if i will attempt

```
http://mysite.test/admin
```

it will redirect me to

```
http://mysite.test/login
```

this is very fine. but now i have subdomain for same site.

```
http://company.mysite.test/
```

and this URL serves as login page as well. but when i hit

```
http://company.mysite.test/admin
```

it is redirecting me to

```
http://company.mysite.test/login
```

which is is entirely wrong. it must be redirected to

```
http://company.mysite.test/
```

for subdomain. what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you login route to `Route::get('/');`

you'll also need to make changes to your Authenticate middleware that manages redirects to login page.